# updating multi series area graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am creating an area graph using d3.

This code works, but I am not happy with the data structure in the update method (toggle), indeed I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

When creating the graph I pass in the data via:

```
data([nsw,qld])
// then draw the chart
```

When I update the graph I pass in the data via:

```
chart.data([nsw]);
// draw the nsw series in the chart
chart.data([qld]);
// draw the qld series in the chart
```

Surely I can update the data by passing it in in the correct format of [nsw,qld]

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <svg id="chart"></svg>

  <script>

  var NSW = "NSW";
  var QLD = "QLD";

  var width = 400;
  var height = 400;

  var years = [1,2,3,4,5];

  var data = years.map(function(){ return [Math.random(),Math.random()]; });   // generate bogus data
  var nsw = data.map(function(d) { return d[0];}); // extract new south wales data
  var qld = data.map(function(d) { return d[1];}); // extract queensland data

  var chart = d3.select("#chart").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append("g");
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, years.length]).range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d[0], d[1]); })]).range([height,0]);
  var area = d3.svg.area().x(function(d,i) { return x(i); }).y0(height).y1(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

  console.log([nsw,qld])

  chart
  .selectAll("path.area")
  .data([nsw,qld])          // !!! here i can pass both arrays in.
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")
  .attr("class", function(d,i) { return [NSW,QLD][i]; })
  .attr("d", area);

  chart.on("click", function() {

    data = years.map(function(){return [ Math.random(),Math.random()];}); // switch in some new random data

    var nsw = data.map(function(d) { return d[0];})
    var qld = data.map(function(d) { return d[1];})

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d[0], d[1]); })]).range([height, 0]);

    var svg = chart.transition();

    /*
    svg
    .selectAll("path")
    .data([nsw,qld])        // !!! this doesn't work.
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); });
    */

    chart.data([nsw]);      // !!! here i'm only passing in one!

    svg.select("path.NSW")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", function(d) {return area(d); });

    chart.data([qld]);      // !!! ...and then another

    svg.select("path.QLD")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); });
  });

  </script>
```

Link to fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MLA3x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a transition in the update part and not a selection. That is, you're calling `.data()` on a transition, which you can't do. It works fine if you add the transition after updating the data:

```
chart
 .selectAll("path")
 .data([nsw,qld])
 .transition()
 .duration(750)
 .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MLA3x/1/).